# how to disable gmail notification sound samsung a50s

Tags: samsung, notifications

I have a Samsung A50s. It is making some sound each time an email arrives in inbox. I am not able to find out how to disable these sounds?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Swipe down from the screen so you see the notification in your notification center. Then, hold down on the notification so that it expands. You can edit the notification settings there. Change the priority so that the sound does not occur anymore (if I'm not mistaken, medium or low priority disables the sound)

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/xScreenshot_20180228-111409.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.jxvpjJzLUN.png

The show silently switch would help here.